# Как поймать $_GET отправленную по WebSocket

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

Я использую WebSocket(Ratchet), проблема заключается в том, что  на сервере надо поймать этот get и с его помощью выводить сообщения уже конкретным людям, но не могу найти.. где его ловить... в чат Chat оно не существует , формат записи:var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080?room=1"); Cервер на php

Comment: Ну, если сервер на РНР )), то ловить надо в массив `$_GET`, точнее в  `$_GET['room']`

Comment: ДА ладно? какой файл...